# How to add transition animation?

Tags: android

The following code will change the size and position of the downBar(ImageView).
In this code, can add TranslateAnimation this?

```
private void downBarResize(int resId) {
    View basic = mContent.findViewById(resId);
    LayoutParams barParams = (LayoutParams) downBar.getLayoutParams();
    barParams.width = basic.getWidth();
    barParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, resId);
    downBar.setLayoutParams(barParams);
}
```

Comment: These links should help you.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html
http://www.edumobile.org/android/category/android-beginner-tutorials/
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html